# Is it possible to insert multiple rows in a table based on a select returning more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Using Oracle SQL, I am trying to insert into table A based on select from table B, but I am not sure how to achieve this, since the select is returning more than one row.

```sql
INSERT INTO A
VALUES
(
SELECT id FROM B WHERE status = 'APPROVED',
'Hardcoded-Value'
);
```

**Table B**:

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | APPROVED |
| 2 | DECLINED |
| 3 | APPROVED |

Based on that insert, I want to achieve following:
**Table A**:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hardcoded-Value |
| 3 | Hardcoded-Value |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a const in the select list

```
INSERT INTO A(colA, colB)
SELECT id, 'Hardcoded-Value'
FROM B
WHERE status = 'APPROVED'
```